# Angular ng-show elements disappearing on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova

I have some very simple ng-show tags in my Angular/Cordova App. On my desktop environment everything works fine but on iOS i've noticed that elements sometimes disappear.

This usually tends to happen once (can't be reproduced after first seen) and re-orienting the screen makes the element appear again. After returning the screen to the original position the bug is fixed as well so I know this isn't a javascript problem on my end. Has anyone else seen this/solved it?

HTML

```
<div ng-if="fullId===false">{{'postcode-not-enough-info'|translate}}</div>

<div class="question-response select-response-container postcode-dialog">
    <span class="select-display">
        <span ng-if="response"
              class="select-label-pos">{{displayResponse}}</span>

        <span ng-if="!response" class="select-label-pos">{{'postcode-select-address'|translate}}</span>
        <span class="ui-icon down-arrow-icon down-arrow-pos"></span>
    </span>
    <select ng-show="fullId===false" class="question-response-select" ng-change="updateDisplayResponse()" ng-options="item.Text as combined(item) for item in options" ng-model="response">
        <option value>{{'postcode-select-address'|translate}}</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-show="fullId===true" class="question-response-select" ng-change="updateDisplayResponse()" ng-options="item.Id as item.Text for item in options" ng-model="response">
        <option value>{{'postcode-select-address'|translate}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="action-bar">
    <button ng-click="okay()" class="action third okay">{{'okay'|translate}}</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.updateDisplayResponse = function(){
            if($scope.fullId === true) {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.options.length; i++) {
                    if ($scope.response === $scope.options[i].Id) {
                        $scope.displayResponse = $scope.options[i].Text;
                    }
                }
            } else{
                for (var x = 0; x < $scope.options.length; x++) {
                    if ($scope.response === $scope.options[x].Text) {
                        $scope.displayResponse = $scope.options[x].Description.substring(0,$scope.options[x].Description.length-1) + ", " + $scope.options[x].Text;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: A code excerpt wouldn't hurt

Comment: Added one, I honestly didn't think it would help since I've seen this problem in two separate locations. The only constant is that ng-hide/show is involved. In this instance the button, select elements and surrounding modal disappear only when the second select element is given a value. But they can be unhidden by re-orienting so its not a javascript thing. Note this same bug occurs outside of modals as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what type of value do you store in `fullId`? The name entails an integer, but you are using it as a boolean. If it is intended to be used as a boolean, then you do not need to explicitly check for true/false, e.g. `ng-if="fullId===false"`, this would be enough: `ng-if="!fullId"`.

Comment: I see your confusion, fullId is definitely a boolean. It refers to postcode service that returns full and partial ids based on how specific information fed into it is. If fullid is false we dont have a specific address but a more general one like the first couple of a digits of a postcode.